# Heroku active storage S3 Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (Net::OpenTimeout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, rails-activestorage

I am having a really weird issue. We are using the following combination

1. Rails 7.0.0 master branch
2. Heroku
3. Active Storage
4. Bucketeer addon
5. Staging app
6. Production app

I have two environments staging and production. On staging everything works fine, on production I keep running into: `Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (Net::OpenTimeout)`. The heroku support was, unfortunately, less than helpful (was worth a shot) so I am asking here.

If I use s3 directly, from a rails console, everything works fine. I can upload and download objects from my bucket so I know for a fact that the environment variables are valid.

If I on the other hand, try to upload a user avatar using active storage I get this error message: `Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (Net::OpenTimeout)`, which, to me, indicates a complete failure to connect to S3.

I have experimented with different timeouts both for active storage's `storage.yml` and for the global amazon configuration with no differing result. The error seems to be returned faster than the timeout (open timeout of 15 seconds should wait 15 seconds but it does not).

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting `config/credentials/production.yml` everything is well.